# The query concerning the Euler-Poincare formula’s generalizations

Tags: euler-characteristics, convex-polytopes, graph-theory, homology

Euler's equation for polyhedral, Euler's polyhedral formula, V – E + F = 2, where V, E, and F, are the number of points, edges and faces, was discovered by Leonhard Euler in 1752. However, the basic idea - not the equation - was revealed much earlier by Descartes & others, and later generalized by Lhuilier, as follow: V – E + F = 2 – 2g, where g is genus, the number of holes or handles. Later on, Schläfli  and Poincare also generalized the formula to the higher dimensional n-polytopes. We talk about Euler-Poincare formula and Euler-Poincare characteristic (X) for combinatorial cell complexes or polyhedral solids: X = N1 – N2 + N3 – N4 + … +/- Nk, where k is the dimension of the complex Nk and X  = 2, if k is odd, or 0, if k is even.

My **question** is:
Are there any other/later  generalizations of this Euler-Poincare characteristic of a cell complex?

Comment: The short answer is that there are too many generalizations to list. One very general example is the Grothendieck group of a triangulated category.

Comment: Thank you. I'm mostly interested about the generalizations with genus.

Comment: The genus computation is a special case of the fact that the Euler characteristic of a polytope is the alternating sum of the dimensions of its homology groups. This generalizes to bounded chain complexes of finite-dimensional vector spaces. 

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article discusses (and provides some references for) [several generalizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Generalizations):

- To a *chain complex*, when the Euler characteristic is the alternating sum of the ranks of the homology groups of the chain complex.
- To a *sheaf* on a projective scheme.
- To an *orbifold*, which may have a fractional Euler characteristic.
- To a bounded finite *poset*.
- To a finite group or *monoid*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I did already study this interesting Wikipedia article. Probably I didn't focus my question enough (first time in mathoverflow). I'm mostly interested about the generalizations, where also the value of genus is aproximated.